# Howto disable iPad menus in iFrame in design mode?

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, designmode, autocorrect

I am implementing an web based editor which uses an iframe in design mode for its content. On usual desktop browsers everything works fine but not on the iPad. Reasons include the standard menus of the ipad: spell checking and copy/paste/replace/bold/italic/underline/...

Is there a way to disable this menus completely? I did some researches but setting spellcheck="false", autocomplete="off" or autocapitalize="off" didn't change anything.

Comment: I've never found one.

Comment: If it is not possible to disable the menus, is it possible to block the action (preventDefault on some events, which events?)?